# How to convert array collection to a dataset c#

Tags: c#, arrays, dataset

Hi have a response class that has three models, all of a certain type...

```
public class AssociationResponse
{
    public AssociationModel ItemDetail {get;set;}
    public AssociationModel[] Children {get;set;}
    public AssociationModel Parent {get; set;}
    
    public int ErrorCode { get; set; }
    public string ErrorMessage { get; set; }
}
```

Now i am struggling in how to convert the AssociationModel[] Children to a simple dataset, so that i can convert them into datatables and show the results in a tree diagram.. unless anybody knows of a better way?

In my code behind

```
public AssociationModel ItemDetail { get; set; } = new AssociationModel();
public AssociationModel Parent { get; set; } = new AssociationModel();
public AssociationModel Child { get; set; } = new AssociationModel();

public async Task LoadData(string SerialNumber)
{
    try
    {
         GetAssociationBySerialNumberRequest request = new GetAssociationBySerialNumberRequest()
         {
             SerialNumber = SerialNumber
         };
    
         response = await IAssociation.AssociationGetData(request);
         AssociationResponse resp = new AssociationResponse();
         if (SerialNumber != null)
         {
             ItemDetail = response.ItemDetail;
             Parent = response.Parent;
             **DataSet dset = new DataSet();**
         }
      }
```

Any help would be greatful. P.S there are three tables within my [] Children.. So i wanted to somehow access them, i have tried saving to a datatable type, but that doesn't work. any help appreciated.

**Edit**

The problem, i am having is that i cant seem to convert the arrays to a dataset. Not sure how to do this.

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure but I think what you are searching for is to create a database with Code-First . With EntityFramework: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/modeling/code-first/workflows/new-database

Comment: The easiest way is to create an interface that returns and item array from AssociationModel.  Then you can add rows to a DataTable : dt.Rows.Add(object[]);

Comment: can anybody help with an example please

Comment: @sinfella It's not clear to me what you need. I have code that can load a datatable from an IEnumerable<T>, and an array is of that type, but I'm not sure that this is what you need. Please edit your question and clarify. We need to be sure what is de input and what should be the output

Comment: if you create a dataset with 3 datatables you can load the three tables from Children in each of them. Every row from Chilren.TableX can be loaded into a datatable with dataTable.LoadDataRow(row from tableX.ToArray(), true)

Comment: Thanks Poiter, do you have an example. sorry. not done this before

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Will this work for you?

I use this extension method to convert IEnumerable to Datatables

```
        public static DataTable ToDataTable<T>(this IList<T> data)
        {
            var props = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(typeof(T));
            var table = new DataTable();
            for (var i = 0; i < props.Count; i++)
            {
                var prop = props[i];
                Type propertyType;
                if (prop.PropertyType.IsGenericType &&
                    prop.PropertyType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(Nullable<>))
                {
                    propertyType = prop.PropertyType.GetGenericArguments()[0];
                }
                else
                {
                    propertyType = prop.PropertyType;
                }

                table.Columns.Add(prop.Name, propertyType);
            }
            var values = new object[props.Count];
            foreach (var item in data)
            {
                for (var i = 0; i < values.Length; i++)
                {
                    values[i] = props[i].GetValue(item);
                }
                table.Rows.Add(values);
            }
            return table;
        }
```

**Edited**

What about this method?

```
public static DataTable ToDataTable(IList<AssociationModel> data)
        {
            var props = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(typeof(AssociationModel));
            var table = new DataTable();
            for (var i = 0; i < props.Count; i++)
            {
                var prop = props[i];
                Type propertyType;
                if (prop.PropertyType.IsGenericType &&
                    prop.PropertyType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(Nullable<>))
                {
                    propertyType = prop.PropertyType.GetGenericArguments()[0];
                }
                else
                {
                    propertyType = prop.PropertyType;
                }

                table.Columns.Add(prop.Name, propertyType);
            }
            var values = new object[props.Count];
            foreach (var item in data)
            {
                for (var i = 0; i < values.Length; i++)
                {
                    values[i] = props[i].GetValue(item);
                }
                table.Rows.Add(values);
            }
            return table;
        }
```

and your code will change like follow

```
    if (SerialNumber != null)
    {
        ItemDetail = response.ItemDetail;
        Parent = response.Parent;
        DataTable dataTable = ToDataTable(response.Children.ToList());
    }
```

Comment: I dont think this will work as i have three tables in my response object that is type array

Comment: @sinfella I added some more code in my answer, that might help. Let me know how it goes

Comment: Perfect. Thank you so much! this has saved me so much time! really appreciate it. I will reward the bounty in 4 hours (As it says). :)